# Is "(p AND q) OR r" logically equivalent to "p AND (q OR r)" ??

Tags: logic, discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra

In the context of discreet math / boolean algebra / logic, is "(p AND q) OR r" logically equivalent to "p AND (q OR r)"? I believe so, but my professor said:

```
They are not the same.  If p is true, q is false, and r is true, then the first expression is false:

(p and q) or r
becomes
(T and F) or T
which is
F or T
which is
F.


But the 2nd expression is p and (q or r) which is (T and (F or T)) = (T and T) = T.
These are different."
```

Is he correct? (Also, please excuse my formatting, this is my first question on Math)

Comment: Your title is considering $p\wedge q \wedge r$ and your professor is talking about $p\wedge q\vee r$. The latter one is ambiguous and you need to add parenthesis.

Comment: I made a copy-and-paste error. In the title and body, it is supposed to be just the second one.

Comment: Then your professor has already gave an example where associativity does not work. What is your doubt then?

Comment: Did you not read the professor's explanation? "F or T which is F.". F AND T makes F, but F OR T makes T. The professor's counter example fails.

Comment: Ok, try $F \wedge T \vee T$.

Comment: p & (q or r) is the same as (p & q) or (p & r).

Answer (score 5):

They are not the same.

```
p q r │ (p∧q)∨r  p∧(q∨r)
──────┼───────────────────
F F F │   F        F
F F T │   T        F     *
F T F │   F        F
F T T │   T        F     *
T F F │   F        F
T F T │   T        T
T T F │   T        T
T T T │   T        T
```

Answer (score 1):

The professor gave a fine explanation. Two propositions are equivalent if and only if for **any** possible assignment of truth values to the variables, the propositions are ***both*** false, or *both* true, under the same assignment. Your professor provided a truth value assignment which renders one proposition *true* and the other, *false*. Hence the propositions cannot be equivalent.

Perhaps it will help to see how the propositions look after applying the distributive law that applies to each proposition you are comparing:

$$(p \land q) \lor r \equiv (p \lor r) \land (q \lor r)$$

$$(p \lor q) \land r \equiv (p \land r) \lor (q \land r)$$

Parentheses are crucial here, since they dictate what to evaluate first, and the order in which to evaluate. Without parentheses, the expressions are ambigous: we cannot conclude anything then. When you have mixed connectives involving, e.g., $\lor, \land$, we cannot use associativity to "mix and match" the variables as we please.

Answer (score 0):

The property that we're talking about is called *Associativity*. It's a property for a single operator $*$ defined as $(a*b)*c=a*(b*c)$. What you have is a $(a*b)+c$ which has 2 operators in it. For more information check out [Associativity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property). Welcome to Mathematics.SE.

Comment: Sorry. The question was supposed to be " is '(p AND q) OR r' logically equivalent to 'p AND (q OR r)'? "